# Parse a graph url from a string

Tags: c#, parsing, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I have the following string:

> [{ "sources": ["https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$count=true&$filter=startswith(displayName,'ConfRoom')"]}]

From this string, I need to parse the url:

> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$count=true&$filter=startswith(displayName,'ConfRoom')

This is what I tried so far:

```
string query = "[{ "sources": ["https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$count=true&$filter=startswith(displayName,'ConfRoom')"]}]"
var queryParts = JArray.Parse(query);
var currentPart = queryParts[0];
var url = currentPart.Value<JArray>("sources");
var urlAsString = Convert.ToString(url);
```

On running this, I see url as:

> [ "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$count=true&$filter=startswith(displayName,'ConfRoom')" ]

How do I update the code to get the url as:

> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$count=true&$filter=startswith(displayName,'ConfRoom')

Comment: Looks like you are asking how to parse json. does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-can-i-deserialize-json-with-c

Comment: You knew how to unpack a json array when you did exactly that for the json array of the query. Then, when getting the sources array, you suddenly seem to have forgotten how to unpack a json array. How comes? Are you distracted? Are you a cat? ;-)

Comment: `Convert.ToString(url[0])`

Comment: You can also check out these examples here for inserting string in .Net: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=net-6.0#get-started-with-the-stringformat-method